# Opencv function - can't put text into image, No suitable conversion cvMat to cvARR

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm having problems with putting text into an image.

```
cvPutText (img, text, cvPoint(pos.x,pos.y), &font, cvScalar(255,255,0));
```

I'm not sure why, but img in the above code is underlined and it says no suitable conversion cv::Mat to cv::Arr.  Here's a condensed version of my program.  Thanks for any suggestions.  I put notes nest to code.

```
//function
double getOrientation(vector<Point> &pts, Mat &img)
{

//this works, no problem with img matrix
circle(img, pos, 3, CV_RGB(255, 0, 255), 2);  


//i copied next 9 lines from another working program
char text[255];                            
sprintf(text, "%d", (int)angle);
CvFont font;
int fontface;
double hScale=1.0;
double vScale=1.0;
int    lineWidth=1;
cvInitFont(&font,CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, hScale,vScale,0,lineWidth);

//here's my problem.  if I erase this line, no bugs. Again, img is underlined
//I've tried using &img, and I get a "bad argument (unknown array type) in unknown function.  c:\slave\builds\winstallermegapack\src\opencv.... \matrix.cpp
cvPutText (img, text, cvPoint(pos.x,pos.y), &font, cvScalar(255,255,0));      }


int main()
{
Mat img = imread("c:\\picture.jpg"); // here i read jpg and store into img

getOrientation(contours[i], img);  // function
}

imshow("Image", img);
char key;
while (true)
```

Comment: the program finds objects from a filtered image.  the getorientation function gets looped for each object it finds

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are mixing legacy cv functions and clases.

IF you are using OpenCV 2.x you should call [putText](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext):

```
putText(Mat& img, const string& text, Point org, int fontFace, double fontScale, Scalar color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, bool bottomLeftOrigin=false )
```

For example, a random copy paste from my code:

```
putText(Image, 
        text,
        Point(a,b),
        FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,
        1,
        cvScalar(0,0,0),
        1, 
        CV_AA);
```

Comment: great, I was also missing one of the parameters before cvscalar.  Thanks for your help